# How to find other parent table entries that have exact same values and number of child table entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

SQL: Returning an id from a table based off the values in the child table.(SQL)(MySQL)

I have 2 tables, Parent (ID), and Child (Value_A, Value_B, ParentID), with a 1->many relationship (Parent has multiple children).

Given an Id for the Parent table, how would I find other entries in the parent table that have the same values and number of Child table entries?

Parent

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Child:

| Value_a | Value_b | ParentId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25 | 1 |
| 20 | 75 | 1 |
| 10 | 50 | 2 |
| 20 | 50 | 2 |
| 10 | 75 | 3 |
| 20 | 25 | 3 |
| 10 | 25 | 4 |
| 20 | 75 | 4 |
| 30 | 25 | 4 |
| 10 | 25 | 5 |
| 20 | 75 | 5 |
| 10 | 25 | 6 |
| 20 | 75 | 6 |

Given Parent ID 1 the expected result is 5, 6.

I've had queries that return Parents with the same Value_A but not Value_B and vice versa.

Comment: Stop posting this post over and over. Fix the one you have using the edit button under your post.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/12492890)

Comment: When you say "exactly the same" what if the other one has all the same plus extra ones?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Explain why the 1st paragraph is there or remove it. If you are trying to refer to another Q&A just put the URL & it will be formatted automatically with its current title. It is not helpful to just dump a link/reference. Quote/paraphrase all & only what is needed to ask with credit & explain clearly what it has to do with your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic [***Relational Division Without Remainder***](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) question.

There are a number of solutions, but the classic one is to first get the total number rows in the original set. Then left-join that set to each potential set, and ensure that all rows match as well as there being the same number of matches as there are in the original set.

```sql
DECLARE @yourId int = 1;
DECLARE @count bigint = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child WHERE ParentId = @yourId);

SELECT *
FROM Parent p
WHERE p.Id <> @yourId
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Child other
    LEFT JOIN Child cThis
       ON cThis.Value_a = other.Value_a
      AND cThis.Value_b = other.Value_b
      AND cThis.ParentId = @yourId
    WHERE other.ParentId = p.Id
    HAVING COUNT_BIG(*) = @count                     -- same number of matches
       AND COUNT_BIG(*) = COUNT_BIG(cThis.ParentId)  -- all rows match
);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/0p934nQO)

For a With Remainder version, just change the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`, and change the `HAVING` to

```sql
    HAVING COUNT_BIG(*) >= @count   -- at least that number of matches
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare sets of values, can use aggregated strings and compare them.

Try this

```
with ChildValues as (
select  Parentid
  ,string_agg(value_a,',') within group (order by value_a) sA
  ,string_agg(value_b,',') within group (order by value_a) sB
from Child
group by ParentId
  ) 
select * 
from ChildValues t1
left join ChildValues t2 
    on t1.sA=t2.sA and t1.sB=t2.sB
    and t1.ParentId<>t2.ParentId
where t1.Parentid=1
```

Result

| Parentid | sA | sB | Parentid | sA | sB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10,20 | 25,75 | 5 | 10,20 | 25,75 |
| 1 | 10,20 | 25,75 | 6 | 10,20 | 25,75 |

Or full query

```
with ChildValues as (
select  Parentid
  ,string_agg(value_a,',') within group (order by value_a) sA
  ,string_agg(value_b,',') within group (order by value_a) sB
from Child
group by ParentId
  ) 
select t1.ParentId, string_agg(t2.parentId,',') within group(order by t2.parentId) Ids
from ChildValues t1
left join ChildValues t2 on t1.sA=t2.sA and t1.sB=t2.sB and t1.ParentId<>t2.ParentId
where t1.Parentid=1
group by t1.ParentId
```

| ParentId | Ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5,6 |